# Coloring some prescribed points in a 2D Graphic

Tags: plotting, equation-solving, graphics, color

I am doing some graphic of roots of the polynomial $f(x)=x^{18}-50x^5-1$. The roots are represented in the complex plane as in figure below:

[image]

To do that, I used the command

`f[x_] :=x^18-50*x^5-1; ComplexListPlot[x /. Solve[f[x] == 0, x],PlotStyle -> PointSize[Large]]`

However, I would like to colour (only) the $5$ inner points in red. Is it possible? Could you please help me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 f[x_] := x^18 - 50*x^5 - 1;

 ComplexListPlot[x /. Solve[f[x] == 0, x], 
  PlotStyle -> PointSize[Large], 
  ColorFunction -> (If[#4 <= .5, Red, Blue] &)]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much!!!

Comment: @Jean, my pleasure. Thank you for the accept.

Answer (score 3):

We can sort the roots by their `Abs` or `Norm` and color the first `k` points in red.

```
f[x_] = x^18 - 50*x^5 - 1;
 sol = SolveValues[f[x] == 0, x];
pts = SortBy[sol, Abs, NumericalOrder];
k = 5;
ComplexListPlot[{pts[[1 ;; k]], pts[[k + 1 ;; -1]]}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Using `RegionMember` can be advantageous if a region definition is available.

```
sol = x /. Solve[f[x] == 0, x] // N
ptsA = ReIm /@ sol // N
```

Find the points from `sol` that are inside the region of interest:

```
pos = RegionMember[Disk[{0, 0}, 0.6], ptsA]
pts01 = Pick[sol, pos]

pts02 = Pick[sol, Not /@ pos]
```

Plot:

```
ComplexListPlot[{pts01, pts02}
 , PlotStyle -> {{AbsolutePointSize[8], Red}, {AbsolutePointSize[8], 
    Blue}}
 , Frame -> True
 , Prolog -> {Lighter@Green, Opacity[0.5], Disk[{0, 0}, 0.6]}
 ]
```

Result:

[image]